# Ubuntu 18.04 black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, prompt

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. My laptop configuration is

- HP 250 G7
- Core i3 Intel 7th gen
- 4 GB RAM
- 1 TB HDD

Problem.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop.

When I start it up it gives a black screen with text, see image given below.

Please help me, I don't want to lose my data.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: my PC graphic : Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2

Comment: What screen comes after that?

Comment: I have already provide the image link above in description

Comment: Black prompt with some text

Comment: And after that complete black in just a second again give prompt with some text

Comment: And again complete blackout

Comment: Got it. Now if you have dual boot, go to ubuntu recovery option(or hold shift while booting). Then you can perform fdisk for disk analysing or open terminal to check for issues

Comment: I have only Ubuntu , no dual boot

Comment: How I can share the picture if I want to share

Comment: Here three option

Comment: Ubuntu ,Ubuntu advanced , system setup

Comment: What should I do now

Comment: Advanced and choose an older kernel.

Comment: Same result after going through recovery mode,

Comment: Can I fix the problem through root via recovery mode, please guide me in root

Comment: While I am giving any command in root it only give the output like "apt: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file : no such file or directory"

Comment: I am sharing the drive link of picture when I go through Ubuntu in grub then black prompt appear and it give https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OltaiaTxJxENjfmNam5Q7D16g2feoOel/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: And another picture of root with some command         https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ocb-KZDI9WtoBQfY6KguhwjDtYcAV2EC/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Picture, when I am click on dpkg : repair ... In recovery mode   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Owbi-Jk5jFj1K5wt7mH5lEhMZQOj_FR7/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Download this file https://transfer.sh/EET504/libgcc_s.so.1 by running `wget`, put it under `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Then try running `apt update`

Comment: When click on "file.io... ".  It says that this file is deleted

Comment: I have updated the link

Comment: How I can access Internet in root , how I connect my mobile hotspot with PC

Comment: Or suggest other way to access Internet in PC

Comment: use a pendrive. put the file there. then access using terminal. cp from there to the dir

Comment: I follow your instruction step by step, now next

Comment: It show after apt update that , 63 packages are updated

Comment: try rebooting. see if it works

Comment: I am very thankful to you sir, thanks for your kind instruction. I get back my Ubuntu with my data

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: Vivek - please do remember to edit your question with any responses - comments are only used to elicit further detail from you..  Please can you tidy up now by editing back into your question further detail that you have responded to.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

1. first start your laptop and after that click on the ESC key just at a glance when your laptop is just start
2. grub option appear there
3. select ubuntu advanced
4. recovery mode
5. click on the root, after clicking it appears like your pc terminal
6. now to access your files root and write permission type this                 mount -o rw,remount /
7. now if you want to store your data in another device like pendrive etc
   then you have to mount your pendrive for this go though this link
   https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1165891
8. but if you want to restore your previous using ubuntu iff in case it showing   libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file
   then follow the procedure
   download this file
   https://transfer.sh/EET504/libgcc_s.so.1
   with wget
   put this file to
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
   and then
   apt update
   after that restart your pc.